# PHP Iterator interface: current() returns underlying array instead of first value

Tags: php, arrays, iterator, iteration

I'm creating a class that implements `Iterator` and `ArrayAccess`. The iterator tests are failing. When I do a `print_r()` on `current($object)`, I get the underlying array, not the first object.

The code below is a sample from my actual class that demonstrates the issue. This is the first time I have implemented `Iterator` in one of my classes, so I'm probably doing this wrong somewhere. What do I need to change to make the iterator work properly?

Code:

```
class Collection implements \ArrayAccess, \Iterator
{
    private $_array = array();

    public function __invoke() { return $this->_array; }
    public function offsetExists($offset) { return array_key_exists($offset, $this->_array); }
    public function offsetGet($offset) { return $this->_array[$offset]; }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) { $this->_array[$offset] = $value; }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) { unset($this->_array[$offset]); }
    public function current() { return current($this->_array); }
    public function key() { return key($this->_array); }
    public function next() { return next($this->_array); }
    public function rewind() { return reset($this->_array); }
    public function valid() { return is_null(key($this->_array)); }
}

class TemporaryTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{

    private $_test_object;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->_test_object = new Collection();
        $this->_test_object['alpha'] = 'blah';
        $this->_test_object['beta'] = 'yada';
        $this->_test_object['gamma']  = 'woot';
    }

    public function testIteratorOnInternalArray()
    {
        $o = $this->_test_object;
        $a = $o();
        $this->assertEquals('blah', current($a));
        $this->assertEquals('yada', next($a));
        $this->assertEquals('woot', next($a));
    }

    public function testIterator()
    {
        print_r(current($this->_test_object));
        $this->assertEquals('blah', current($this->_test_object));
        $this->assertEquals('yada', next($this->_test_object));
        $this->assertEquals('woot', next($this->_test_object));
        $this->assertFalse($this->_test_object->valid());
        reset($this->_test_object);
        $this->assertEquals('blah', current($this->_test_object));
    }

    public function testForEach()
    {
        $actual = array();
        foreach ($this->_test_object as $key => $value) { $actual[$key] = $value; }
        $this->assertEquals(array('alpha' => 'blah', 'beta' => 'yada','gamma' =>  'woot'), $actual);
    }
}
```

Unit test output:

```
.FArray
(
    [alpha] => blah
    [beta] => yada
    [gamma] => woot
)
F                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

There were 2 failures:

1) TemporaryTest::testIterator
Array (...) does not match expected type "string".

/Users/mac/Projects/NetShapers/Gears/core/Tests/Unit/TemporaryTest.php:83

2) TemporaryTest::testForEach
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
-    'alpha' => 'blah'
-    'beta' => 'yada'
-    'gamma' => 'woot'
 )

/Users/mac/Projects/NetShapers/Gears/core/Tests/Unit/TemporaryTest.php:97
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expect?

When you call `current($a)` you actually call system function `current()` on your collection, not the internal method `Collection::current()`.

Just calll it  like this to get what you want:

```
$this->assertEquals('blah', $a->current());
```

These methods would be called automatically by the system if you could use your collection in `foreach` for example.

---

> Additional fixes after comment.

You have an error in `valid` method, that's why `foreach` fails for you.

Declaration should look like that:

```
public function valid() 
{ 
    return !is_null(key($this->_array));
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I expect. Did you see the part where the `foreach` test fails as well?

Comment: @JayBienvenu I've updated the answer with the reason why your `foreach` fails

Comment: So the answer is that I had a typo in `valid()`, and `current()` doesn't work with Iterator like `count()` and other functions do?

Comment: @JayBienvenu not exactly. Other functions (next, reset) won't work for you too. `testIterator` fails on first assertion with `current`, so you did not see other errors. Please take a look: https://3v4l.org/KpE85